# Seeking a 1970s (or earlier) novel involving time-travel and ecological conservation

Tags: story-identification, books

Asking on behalf of a friend of an acquaintance via another site :-)

Seeking a 1970s (or earlier) novel involving time-travel and ecological conservation.  From description provided:

> It involved time travel (unexplained) with a girl, from a future so polluted that there weren't any animals but humans any more, traveling back in time to the mid-20th century and meeting her grandfather or great-grandfather or some such who would grow up to be a famous conservationist. She tries to fit in in the new time and fails.

Eventually,

> she finds her way home, and her ancestor gives her some animals to take with her. I specifically remember wolf cubs. (I did not, at that age, wonder what on earth wolves would eat if the future folks ever tried to establish a wild population again. Now... I do wonder. I wonder about lack of genetic diversity, too.)

Description

> The copy I read didn't have a dust jacket. I'm pretty sure the cover was light, between white and yellow, and the art was in shades of gray and showed the main character and possibly some animals.

Comment: Sounds like a YA book I read, except the animals she was given were a pair of rabbits. There was a scene at the end where she convinces the bully who stole her enviro suit to give it back so she can put it on, hoping this will return her to her time, but it doesn't work, Can't recall the title, sorry.